# How to change the float number 0.0521000 to 5.21 in javscript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Here is the float number = 0.0521000

I tried `parseFloat(0.0521000).toFixed(2)`

the output is `0.05`

But my expected output is `5.21`

How to achieve using javascript, es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only math here. Multiply it by 100 and then use .toFixed(2)

```
parseFloat(number * 100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Or just `(0.0521000 * 100).toFixed(2)`... it's already a number, it doesn't need to be parsed.